# How to display gridview data in popup in .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Now i have been created to display gridview data in new tab on click event.

But i need to display in popup.

Here is my code:

```
protected void loginfo_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)(sender);
            Response.Write("<script>");
            Response.Write("window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank')"); 
            Response.Write("</script>");
        }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="bookid" EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White"  Height="240px" 
        Width="755px" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="2px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Book_id" >
            <ControlStyle BorderColor="Red" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bookid" HeaderText="bookid" SortExpression="bookid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="studentid" HeaderText="studentid" SortExpression="studentid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="returndate" HeaderText="returndate" SortExpression="returndate" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="returnstatus" HeaderText="returnstatus" SortExpression="returnstatus" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" SortExpression="Section" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />

            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

and finally cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_logdetails", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", Request.QueryString["id"]);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

I'm new to use jquery in .net, Is there possible to create popup without using DLL and only using in jquery.

Can anyone guide me to fix this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: using `twitter-bootstrap`?

Comment: nope.. javascript or jquery its enough..

Comment: Then you might need to `construct` your `modal` and disable your `loginfo_click` click..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: can you please elaborate your comments as answer?

Comment: For that I might need you rendered `html` for `GridView`.. Could you please post that?

Comment: gridview only.. I posted all the code..when i click loginfo button, it shows gridview data in new tab.. but i need to display in popup,,

Comment: **Rendered `html` for `Gridview`**.. I mean from browser you need to pick up that code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99877/discussion-between-rani-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: You can use BlockUI, fancybox plugin or you can create your own popup.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: can you show your answer? thanks

Comment: Please visit http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page

Comment: @Rani have you checked this link ?